# ERROR: could not insert 'vboxguest': No such device

Tags: linux, virtualbox

I have a problem to run vboxguest on Arch linux,

I retrieve this error when type modprobe -av vboxguest:

```
[root@mic3ael mic3ael]# modprobe -av vboxguest
insmod /lib/modules/4.3.3-2-ARCH/extramodules/vboxguest.ko.gz
modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxguest': No such device
```

then I found that vguest exist on the system:

```
[root@mic3ael mic3ael]# find /lib/modules/ -iname "vbox*"
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxnetflt.ko.gz
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxguest.ko.gz
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxpci.ko.gz
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxnetadp.ko.gz
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxsf.ko.gz
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxvideo.ko.gz
/lib/modules/extramodules-4.3-ARCH/vboxdrv.ko.gz
```

The question is how to run vboxguest on arch linux?

Comment: I have started an Arch Linux Forum discussion about this: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1613118#p1613118

Comment: Is Arch Linux your host or your guest OS?

Comment: Arch linux is host, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

The Arch Linux Forum post: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1613118#p1613118 quickly lead to an answer. For me, Arch Linux is the host, so I should not have installed `virtualbox-guest-utils` which also installed `virtualbox-guest-dkms` as a dependency.

I removed both of those with `sudo pacman -Rsn virtualbox-guest-utils`.

If Arch Linux is your host, you need to install `virtualbox-guest-iso` in the host Arch Linux. Inside the guest OS, it will show up as a CD (or manually point/mount the virtual CD to the host OS path /usr/lib/virtualbox/additions/VBoxGuestAdditions.iso) and you can install from there to get vboxguest working.

If Arch Linux is your guest, then you apparently need to install `virtualbox-guest-utils` inside your Arch Linux guest OS.

Whether host or guest, virtualbox with Arch Linux now also needs `linux-headers` (or any of the following to match the type of kernel you are using: linux-lts-headers linux-zen-headers linux-grsec-headers).

Since the overall installation is kind of complicated, I refer you to the Arch Wiki.

Arch Linux Host: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_steps_for_Arch_Linux_hosts

Arch Linux Guest: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/VirtualBox#Installation_steps_for_Arch_Linux_guests

Comment: Be wary of the -Rsn... I was dumb and distracted and ended up deleting the only kernel i had + i also trashed the bootloader.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem and I fixed it by reinstalling the modules with dkms:

1. `sudo dkms remove vboxhost/5.0.14`
2. `sudo dkms install vboxhost/5.0.14`

Comment: This didn't work. First of all, dkms says it needs either `--all` or `-k kernel-version` after what you've got. Of course, I changed 5.0.14 to the current version (5.0.16). Second of all, it complains that there is no vboxhost version 5.0.16 in the dkms tree. Going on to install it anyway, still have the same error mentioned in this question.

Answer (score -2):

## Problem Description

I just had similar problem on Ubuntu (HOST) with VirtualBox running Debian (GUEST).

The problem is strongly (and confusingly) related to other tasks and errors:

1. Change of screen resolution requires VBoxGuestAdditions installation.
2. The installation using VirtualBox's menu Devices -> Inset Guest Additions CD (Host+D) may lead to "Unable to insert the virtual optical disk" with "(VERR_PDM_MEDIA_LOCKED)" error messages.
3. VBoxGuestAdditions are present in many package repositories and can be installed by the package systems like apt or yum.

   ```
   [...@ubuntu]# apt-get install virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
   ```
4. The installation from repo may NOT improved the resolution.
5. Manual run of VBoxGuestAddition's main script may lead to another error

   ```
   [...@ubuntu]# /usr/share/virtualbox/VBoxLinuxAdditions.sh
   (modprobe vboxguest failed)
   ```
6. The same error then comes from VBoxGuestAdditions init script

   ```
   [...@ubuntu]# /etc/init.d/vboxadd setup
   (modprobe vboxguest failed)
   ```
7. The failure is caused by existing but unloaded kernel module **vboxguest.ko**.
8. Manual deploying of the kernel module into kernel gives another error

   ```
   [...@ubuntu]# modprobe vboxguest
   modprobe: ERROR: could not insert 'vboxguest': No such device
   ```
9. The dmesg may contain error message

   ```
   [...] vboxguest: PCI device not found, probably running on physical hardware.
   ```

## Initial Problem

All those errors have the same initial mistake: **running GUEST apps on HOST**. I think its the same case for your error, because arch linux is supported by the app - see part of the **/etc/init.d/vboxadd** script:

```
if [ -f /etc/arch-release ]; then
    system=arch
elif ... 

if [ "$system" = "arch" ]; then
    USECOLOR=yes
    . /etc/rc.d/functions
    fail_msg() {
        stat_fail
    }

    succ_msg() {
        stat_done
    }

    begin() {
        stat_busy "$1"
    }
fi
```

## Solution

Be careful about which part of VBox runs on GUEST and which one on HOST:

1. Install VirtualBox on HOST (ubuntu in my case) as

   ```
   [...@ubuntu]# apt-get install virtualbox
   ```
2. Install VBoxGuestAdditions et.al. into GUEST (debian in my case)

a) add 'contrib' repository to your repository source list

b) install virtualbox guest-related apps into GUEST

```
[...@debian]# apt-get install virtualbox-guest-utils virtualbox-guest-x11
    virtualbox-guest-dkms virtualbox-guest-additions-iso
```

## GUI and Docs Criticism

The virtualization docs usually state that **GUEST is independent on HOST** and that **VBox runs on HOST**. This:

1. Leads to misunderstanding that user never installs any part of VBox on GUEST
2. Improves chances of user's mistake, because VBox GUI's menu

   Device -> Install Guest Additions CD

invokes feeling of software going to be installed on HOST.

Comment: Maybe there is something to your answer, but it was probably downvoted since so much of it doesn't apply to Arch Linux. The question was about running it on Arch Linux, and apt-get install, adding repos, etc. don't apply to Arch Linux.

Comment: I went ahead and installed the VBoxGuestAdditions on the Guest machine (Windows XP) which worked inside the virtual machine, but still the error mentioned in this question remains.

Comment: In Arch Linux, the package that provides the virtual CD that can be installed inside the Guest is `virtualbox-guest-iso`. That package is working properly. The problem package is `virtualbox-guest-dkms` which is something very recently added to Arch Linux. The previous method was working without this error. I suspect it's a bug, but not sure yet, so started the discussion: https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?pid=1613118#p1613118